# fadein fadeout jquery on mouse-over

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have three sections with a default logo...left,middle and right..on mouse over all sections are changing one by one with their own respective logo.

When I mouse-over the left section it has changed with its logo but the problem is when I mouse-over that logo on left section its turned into the default section ( means left section vanished along with its logo)that I don't want.

I need the mouse effect will be Off when i mouse-over the left section logo, same thing will be applicable on the other two section..

The Html :

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="logo">
        <img src="http://wphooper.com/svg/examples/circle_filled_with_pattern.svg">
    </div>
    <div class="main" id="left">
        <div class="dot1-top">
            <img src="http://www.subblue.com/assets/0000/2881/circle-guide_square.gif" width="53" height="52" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="showhide">
            <div class="main1 hide" style="background-image:url(http://bestwallpaperhd.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/vector-art-background.jpg)"></div>            
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main"  id="middle">
        <div class="dot2-top"><img src="http://www.subblue.com/assets/0000/2881/circle-guide_square.gif" width="53" height="52" alt=""></div>
        <div class="showhide2">
            <div class="main2 hide2" style="background-image:url(http://www.vectorfree.com/media/vectors/yellow-background-red-swirl.jpg)">
            </div>            
        </div>           
    </div>
    <div class="main"  id="right">
        <div class="dot3-top"><img src="http://www.subblue.com/assets/0000/2881/circle-guide_square.gif" width="53" height="52" alt=""></div>
        <div class="showhide3">
            <div class="main3 hide3" style="background-image:url(http://hdwallpaper2013.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/Windows-7-Background-HD-Wallpaper-1080x675.jpg)">
            </div> 
        </div>     
    </div>
</div>
```

And Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swati712/3z6NA/)

Comment: my link [link](http://jsfiddle.net/swati712/3z6NA/)

Comment: Did you consider using [jQuery's :not() selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)? You could use that here to not bind the hover event on the .logo class.

Comment: @roy712 Is this http://jsfiddle.net/3z6NA/2/ fits your need?

Comment: @user1671639 It remain the same as it used to be..as you can see when you mouse-over left section background, the football logo appear. When I mouse over in that football logo section, the whole left section disappear along with football logo. I want the football logo be there when I mouse-over the whole football logo section. Do you get my point?

Comment: Also I don't understand your following script: $(".logo").css('background', bg); Am I going to put some code in CSS to make this work?

Comment: @roy712 No.  After hovering I'm setting the background of `logo-left` to `.log`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you need but I did a little cleanup to your markup and CSS and came up with this solution for the hover effects

```
$('.bg').hide();
$('.main').hover(function (){
    $(this).siblings('.main').find('.bg').stop().fadeOut();
    $(this).find('.bg').stop().fadeIn();
    $('#logo img').attr('src',$(this).data('logo'));
}, function () {});
$('#container').mouseleave(function(){
    $('#logo img').attr('src',$(this).data('logo'));
    $('.main .bg').stop().fadeOut();
});
```

You can check the **[updated fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/TFAYn/3/)**

Comment: Big thanks for your help :) its almost what I want..need just few adjustment..there are 3 positions (left, middle and right) and I want is the background image will be changed whatever position you will mouseover (only image change not logo). Once I mouse-over any particular section like MIDDLE PART, the middle part background image and its logo will show. And if I mouse-over that logo in left section since half of its stand in left section, it will show left background image and its logo since I am entering in left section.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not quite following... You have 3 main sections (left,middle,right) that will change background on hover, I'm good there. Now, is the logo always visible? if not when is it supposed to appear/change src?

Comment: Yes, you are good in first part. There will be one default logo when nothing is selected as it is right now. So that part is also right. Now for 3 main sections it have its 3 own logo. Once you are in left section zone it will show left logo (football) and once you are in middle section zone it will show middle logo and so for with the right. Logo will only be appear when you are in that particular zone/area (left, middle, right). And it will change when you left that particular sections.

Comment: So each section has its own logo that appears when you hover over it, that's 3 logos plus the default one. Do all this logos have to show in the big image on the center of the page or is that one static and the other small images (circle-guide-square) are the ones that change src?

Comment: The default logo will show only when we are out of the 3 section. Once we are in a particular section then only that section background image and its logo will show. And no matter where we mouse-over the entire left section, the left background image and its logo will be fixed. And it will only change if we go to other section like Middle or Right. So basically each section (means image and logo) will show only when mouse-over that particular section. Once we enter different section (middle, right) then it will show their image and logo. And those small images are nothing. It just the design.

Comment: Those small yellow/blue images (circle-guide-square) are just for show-off nothing else. In your given example, when I mouse-over left section the blue background image appear along with its football logo. This is fine. But that football logo is standing in both left and middle section. So when I mouse-over football logo in middle part section, it supposed to turn into Middle background image along with its logo since I am entering Middle Section. But right now its not. So that the thing I want. Hope you are getting the idea what I am trying to say.

Comment: @koala_dev-hope I will hear from you soon

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a hover effect on the class logo-middle.

e.g.

```
$(".logo-middle").hover(function mouseIsOverImage() {
    /* keep the image */
}, function mouseIsOffImage() {
    /* make the image what it was before */
});
```

By the way, you also should adjust your hover functions to clear the animation queue.  If you quickly mouse over and off of the sections several times you'll see that there are many animations that get queued up and then all continue run until they're done.  $.clearQueue() should do the trick.

Comment: can u put the whole code in a link so i can understand it better?It would be a great help :)